# take only the value from stream if the value changes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a stream with Rxjs to follow the loading status. I get mainly `pending - pending - pending - success - success 0 - success` But I want to take only `pending - success`  case. If first value is `pending` and second value is `pending` too, don't take it.

dashboard.component.ts

```
export enum Status {
  pending = 'pending',
  error = 'error',
  success = 'success'
}

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    public loadingStatusOrders$: Observable<Status>;

    constructor(private readonly store: Store) {
    this.loadingStatusOrders$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(selectLoadingStatusAll),
      filter((status) => !!status),
         );
     }


}
```

Which operator should I use to implement above logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinctUntilChanged`  operator for that:

```
this.loadingStatusInquiries$ = this.store.pipe(
  select(selectLoadingStatusAll),
  filter((status) => !!status),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
);
```

Comment: It seems that this is what I am looking for. But the problem stays the same. Any idea?

Comment: what's problem you have now?

Comment: It is ok now. No need to use it anymore as the causing problem is solved. Danke